# Understanding bindings in IIS on Azure VM

Tags: azure, iis

I have a VM in Azure with IIS running and hosting a website.  This site was originally written and hosted by another company and they recently moved it to this VM for us.  The binding still shows as the old website name (as hosted on the other company's site) and we still access it by going to the original website URL name in our browser.  The developer mentioned to me that I'd need to eventually change the binding to reflect something hosted by my company.

My question is what is my next step?  I know how to change the binding, but I'm having trouble knowing what to change it to?  Ideally, I'd like to have the site hosted in Azure - the url name does not matter to me, as long as I can change it from the old original one.  I created a new Web App in Azure and am trying to point the website to that new url but it's not working.  Not sure that's the best route anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, Original website may have a domain name associated with it. You will have to update the DNS records with PIP (static-public IP) of Azure VM (site is now running on IIS on Azure VM).

Trust this helps.

Comment: Mihir, I'm trying to follow all the rules here but I'm not even allowed to use the comments section to thank you.  Oh well, if it means breaking the rules to tell you thank you for your help, I don't care, I'm breaking them!  Thank you!